# accessing route in laravel 4 does not work in LAMP

Tags: php, laravel-4, lamp

hey guys im new to laravel then im starting to access the home using

```
Route::get('/home', function()
{   
    //return 'foo';
return View::make('hello');
});
```

with url: http://web.learninglaravel.dev/home, before with this url i can access the home with route '/' without using the php artisan serve. Im using ubuntu 12.04. and my directory is like this

[image]

because im using mod_vhost_alias

and the browser gives me this 
[image]

please help because im a newbie in laravel. tnx in advanced..

Comment: if you can access the apache error log it should give you a more detailed reason for the 500 error - if you can add the line from the error log to your post it might help diagnose the error - apache error log is probably at /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: [Thu Dec 12 11:37:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove or add the / on index.php.

Without

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

With

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "/" from "/home".  Just "home" will fix this.

Code:

```
Route::get('home', function()
{   
    //return 'foo';
return View::make('hello');
});
```

I've made this mistake once or twice  :)

Comment: Have you created an .htaccess file to remove "index.php" from your URL?

Have you also moved your "public" folder?  If you haven't, you'll need to access this via web.learninglaravel.com/public/home

Comment: what can i put to my .htaccess to remove the index.php && where can i put it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured your url (or virtual host if you have created one) to point to the public folder.

If you have done that and you still can't access the folder change the permissions to allow www-data access.

Run this command on the folder :

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data foldername
```

You might also have to change permissions to the storage folder once you get this phase working.

Comment: its working now i put some script on .htaccess to remove the index.php and its working now tnx btw..